# Make View fill Wrap Content Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-relativelayout

I have a layout that should wrap the views inside for which I used wrapcontent. Then, how would I put another view in that same layout the same height as the layout with the wrapped views inside that layout. I tried using match_parent inside wrap_content but that wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: post your xml code...